# Dovecot compress existing maildir mails from postfix

Tags: debian, compression, zlib, dovecot, maildir

I've taken code snippets from elsewhere and created a script to compress existing maildir emails (Dovecot would need to be stopped as I don't check for locks).

```
#!/bin/bash
store=/var/vmail/mydomain.com
find "$store" -type d -name "cur" | while read maildir; do

  tmpdir=$(cd "$maildir/../tmp" &>/dev/null && pwd) || exit 1

  find=$(find "$maildir" -type f -name "*,S=*" ! -name "*,*:2,*,*Z*" -printf "%f\n")
  if [ -z "$find" ]; then
    echo continue
    continue
  fi

  echo "$find" | while read filename; do

    if file "$maildir/$filename" | grep -q "SMTP mail, "; then

      echo 'Uncompressed' "$filename"

      flags=$(echo $filename | awk -F:2, '{print $2}')

      if echo $flags | grep ','; then
        newname=$filename"Z"
      else
        newname=$filename",Z"
      fi

      srcfile="$maildir/$filename"
      tmpfile="$tmpdir/$filename"
      dstfile="$maildir/$newname"

      gzip -c "$srcfile" > "$tmpfile" &&
      chown --reference="$srcfile" "$tmpfile" &&
      chmod --reference="$srcfile" "$tmpfile" &&
      touch --reference="$srcfile" "$tmpfile"

      if [ -f "$srcfile" ] && [ -f "$tmpfile" ]; then
        mv "$tmpfile" "$srcfile" &&
        mv "$srcfile" "$dstfile"
      else
        rm -f "$tmpfile"
      fi

    elif file "$maildir/$filename" | grep -q "gzip compressed data"; then
      echo 'Compressed' "$filename"
    else
      echo 'Unknown type'
    fi

  done
done
```

However I realised that my inbound mail doesn't get found, as not all of the emails meet the find criteria of `-name "*,S=*"`

Example

```
find "/var/vmail/mydomain.com" -type d -name "cur" | while read maildir; do find "$maildir" -type f -name "*,S=*" ! -name "*,*:2,*,*Z*" -printf "%f\n"; done
```

Will find these:

```
/var/vmail/mydomain.com/Maildir/.Sent/cur
1580000001.M10001P10008.ip-172-1-1-100,S=14037,W=14302:2,Sa
1580000002.M20002P10009.ip-172-1-1-100,S=3784,W=3888:2,S
```

However not these:

```
/var/vmail/mydomain.com/Maildir/.INBOX/cur
1580000003.Vca01I80f58M300003.ip-172-1-1-100:2,S
1580000004.Vca01I80de7M400004.ip-172-1-1-100:2,Sa
1580000005.Vca01I85252M400005.ip-172-1-1-100:2,RS
1580000006.Vca01I83ffeM400006.ip-172-1-1-100:2,Sb
1580000007.Vca01I8159aM400007.ip-172-1-1-100:2,RSa
1580000008.Vca01I84015M400008.ip-172-1-1-100:2,Sab
```

I could easily change the find command to match the inbound mail but as the find criteria came from elsewhere I wondered if there was a reason for the explicit `"*,S=*"`?

Ps. Please note that mail is not received through Dovecot, inbound mail is picked up by **postfix which saves the mail directly to the relevant directory**, postfix variables below for an example.

```
virtual_mailbox_base: /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps: ldap lookup, %d/%u/Maildir/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider searching for substring `:2,` in filenames.

[Dovecot: Maildir filename extensions](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir#Maildir_filename_extensions)

> The standard filename definition is: ":2,".  […]
>   * ,S=:  contains the file size. Getting the size from the filename avoids doing a stat(), which may improve the performance. This is especially useful with Maildir++ quota.
>   * ,W=:  contains the file's RFC822.SIZE, ie. the file size with linefeeds being CR+LF characters. […]

Uppercase letters mark "standard flags", lowercase letters mean "local/user flags".

Comment: Perfect well detailed response, changing from -name "*,S=*" to -name "*:2,*" seems to do the job.